# Android - set\define emulator's port

Tags: android, android-emulator, telnet

Is there any way to define the port number of the Android emulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

```
emulator -port <port> -avd <avd_name>
```

> The console port number must be an even integer between 5554 and 5584, inclusive. +1 must also be free and will be reserved for ADB.

Refer to [Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) for command line parameters for emulator.

Comment: Did not see it on the documentation. Thanks.